# Can't Tell If Fetch Or Relationship Is The Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am adding object exercise to object session (as a relationship).

In a view, I want to fetch and display exercises for a particular session object.

Right now it is showing all exercises in the database rather than just for that session object.

The relationship between the two objects is called "exercises".

This is the current code I am using for the fetch if anyone can help me.

```
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
// Edit the entity name as appropriate.
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

LogResultsViewController *logResultsTableViewController = [[LogResultsViewController alloc]init];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"exercises = %@", logResultsTableViewController.selectedSession]];

// Set the batch size to a suitable number.
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

// Edit the sort key as appropriate.
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
```

Updated Code:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
NSSet *exercises = [self.selectedSession valueForKey:@"exercises"];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:YES]];
NSArray *sorted = [exercises sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
sorted = self.exerciseArray;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [exerciseArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [exerciseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

When I NSLog the selectedSession, here is what it shows:

`selectedSession: <Session: 0x7336940> (entity: Session; id: 0x7334f70 <x-coredata://17D44726-23F7-402F-9CBE-2EED96212E14/Session/p1> ; data: {
    exercises = "<relationship fault: 0x5d34680 'exercises'>";
    timeStamp = "2011-05-31 04:41:07 +0000";`

Also, when I NSLog the NSSset called exercises, I get:
`Relationship fault for (<NSRelationshipDescription: 0x711b370>), name exercises, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Session, renamingIdentifier exercises, validation predicates (
), warnings (
), versionHashModifier (null), destination entity Exercise, inverseRelationship exercises, minCount 0, maxCount 0 on 0x7140790`

Update:

Ok so I changed the code in cellForRowAtIndex to have
`Exercise *exercise = (Exercise *)[exerciseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 cell.textLabel.text = exercise.name;`

Now it shows the exercise name but it is showing the same list of exercises for all sessions, instead of just for the session to which it belongs to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your instances of `Session` have a relationship to instances of `Exercise`, you don't need to do another fetch to get the session's exercises. You can just follow the relationship and get them directly-- they'll be loaded automatically. From your code it looks like `logResultsTableViewController.selectedSession` is an instance of `Session`. If that's the case, you can get all of that session's exercies as follows (assuming the relationship is called `exercises`):

```
NSSet *exercises = [logResultsTableViewController.selectedSession valueForKey:@"exercises"];
```

You can then sort that NSSet as needed.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I think that is exactly what I needed.  If I do this,  am I supposed to create a NSArray from this NSSet, with something like `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[inSet allObjects]];`?  Also, if I do this, can I get rid of all my fetchresults related code in this view?  What if I want to delete an instance of exercise from this view?

Comment: Well, `[inSet allObjects]` is already an array, so the rest isn't needed unless you need the array to be mutable. Looking at your code above you could do something like `NSArray *sorted = [inSet sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors]`.

Comment: Ok cool, I'm going to try this now.  I can get rid of all fetchresults related code from this viewController correct?  But what if I want to delete an instance of exercise?  Can I still do this?

Comment: I've also added my new code to the question if you can look at it.  The table is not showing any data though.  I'm not sure if something is wrong with this code, or if the instance of exercise is not getting added to session properly.

Comment: To answer the first comment, if you're going to be deleting entries then you do need to convert to a mutable array. For the second question, your table view callbacks make use of `exerciseArray`, but there's no sign that you have ever assigned any data to this variable. As a result the table has no data to show. It looks like the last line in `viewDidLoad` has the assignment backwards.